# Exporting information of multiple objects?

Tags: python, objects, export, file-format

Is it possible to export a text file containing the information of models placed in a scene such as *Location*, *Size*, and *Rotation*?

So if I had two cubes, it'd make a text file with something along the lines of

```
Location: X:11 Y:30 Z:20 Scale: X:40 Y:20 Z: 15 Rotation: X:15 Y:123 Z: 180, 
Location: X:18 Y:20 Z:10 Scale: X:20 Y:40 Z: 30 Rotation: X:20 Y:140 Z: 90
```

for both of the cubes in the scene.

Comment: yes it is possible, but what have tried till now

Comment: see [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this script work for all the mesh in the scene and save the data.txt in the same path as you blend file is save..... If you don't save the blend file the script don't work

best

```
    import bpy

def grados(radianes):
    x= (180*radianes)/3.141516
    return x


#open path_file where I will save
full_filel = bpy.data.filepath.split("\\")
#print(full_filel)
#print(len(full_filel))
contador = 1 
path_file = full_filel[0]

while contador != len(full_filel)-1:
    path_file = str(path_file) + "\\" + str(full_filel[contador])
    contador +=1

#path_file actual
print(path_file)

#file name

file_name = "data.txt"

#path blend file
file1 = open((path_file + '\\' + file_name), 'w', encoding = "utf-8")

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for ob in objects:
    if ob.type =="MESH":
        name = ob.name
        loc = tuple(ob.location)
        sc = tuple(ob.scale)
        rot = [grados(ob.rotation_euler[0]), grados(ob.rotation_euler[1]), grados(ob.rotation_euler[2])]

        #print(name, " ", loc, " ", sc, " ", rot)

        dato = (ob.name," Location: ", loc, " Scale: ", sc, " Rotation: ", rot )
        #write data in file
        file1.write(str(dato) + "\n")


#close the file
file1.close()
```